Limit for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$
So I'm in the limit section of a calc 1 book, right before one sided limits, and one of the questions is
Find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha(\small\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}-\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x+2})$$$$
\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$$
I've tried to factor out the square root using a conjugate
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha\frac{(\small\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}-\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x+2})(\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}+\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x+2})}{\small\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}+\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x+2}}} $$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha\frac{\small\frac{x-1}{x}+\frac{x+1}{x+2}}{\small\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}+\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x+2}}$$
Which doesn't seem to help
How do I solve this?

The denominator in your last expression tends to $2$.

The last numerator is wrong. I agree that it's hard to arrive to a conlcusion without a function $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\in\Bbb R\setminus{0}$, a polynomial $P$ and an expression in the form $x^\alpha\frac{P(x)}{x^\beta f(x)}$.

The last expression should be $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha\frac{\small\frac{x-1}{x}-\frac{x+1}{x+2}}{\small\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}+\sqrt\frac{x+1}{x+2}}$$
The denominator tends to $2$, while the numerator is $$-\frac{2}{x(x+2)}$$
This may be substituted by $$-\frac{2}{x^2}$$ as the limit of the quotient of both is $1$.
Therefore, the limit is the same as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}-x^\alpha\frac{2}{2x^2}=-x^{\alpha-2}$$
We conclude if $\alpha>2$ this limit is obviously $-\infty$, if $\alpha=2$ the limit is $-1$, and if $\alpha<2$ the limit is $0$.

Yep same result. One thing. If we did all this without rationalisation, we would get $$ \lim_{x\to \infty } x^\alpha \bigg( \sqrt {1-\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x+2}} \bigg)$$ This gives us that it tends to zero. But it's simply not true $\forall \alpha$. Why this flaw?

That does not necessarily tend to $0$ ($0\cdot\infty$ situation)

yeah I just checked on desmos. And kind of understood it too. Thanks.
